# How to prove the following optimization result from Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Currently, I am working on a decision problem in Telecommunication. This problem is reformulated under a form of Optimization problem that is:

$$\begin{gathered}
  {\text{Minimize}}\,\,\,A \hfill \\
  st.\,\,\,\frac{{a\left( {\left( {{t^2} - 1} \right){S_1} + {{\left( {\frac{B}{A}} \right)}^2}{{\left( {{t^2} + 1} \right)}^2} - 4{t^2}} \right)}}{{\left( {{{\left( {\frac{B}{A}} \right)}^2} - 1} \right){{\left( {{t^2} + 1} \right)}^2}}} + D\left( {\frac{2}{{1 + {t^2}}} - 1} \right) \leqslant \frac{{2t}}{{{{\left( {{t^2} + 1} \right)}^2}}}\left( {a\left( {1 - {t^2}} \right) - {S_2}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Where $a > 0,A>0, B > 0, C > 0, 0 < \frac{B}{A} < 1$ and the term ${S_1}$ and ${S_2}$ are given as:

$\begin{gathered}
  {S_1}^2 = {\left( {\frac{B}{A}} \right)^2}{\left( {{t^2} + 1} \right)^2} - 4{t^2} \hfill \\
  {S_2}^2 = {\left( {\frac{1}{{BC}}} \right)^2}{\left( {{t^2} + 1} \right)^2} - 4{a^2}{t^2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

Note that the term $D$ is guarantee to be negative ($D<0$). Also, the term $t = \tan \left( {\frac{\theta }{2}} \right)$ where the angle $0 < \theta  < \frac{\pi }{2}$ which lead to $0 < t < 1$.

Practically speaking, there is also a constraint for how large and how small the value of $A$ should be that is $0 < {M_L} < A < {M_U}$. However, the physical range $\left| {{M_U} - {M_L}} \right|$ is quite large so this constraint can be dropped.

The followings is the code for invoking Mathematica parametric optimization:

```
Minimize[{A,(a*((t^2-1)Subscript[S, 1]+(B/A)^2 (t^2+1)^2-4t^2))/(((B/A)^2-1)*Power[t^2+1,2])+D*(2/(1+t^2)-1)<= (2*t)/Power[t^2+1,2] (a*(1-t^2)-Subscript[S, 2])&&D<0&&0<t<1 &&Power[Subscript[S, 2],2]==Power[1/(B*C),2]*(t^2+1)^2-4*a^2*t^2&&a>0&&B>0&&C>0&&A>0&&0<B/A<1&&Power[Subscript[S, 1],2]==(B/A)^2*(t^2+1)^2-4*t^2&&0<Subscript[M, L]<A<Subscript[M, U]&&Subscript[S, 1]>0&&Subscript[S, 2]>0},{A}]
```

Which give the minimizer is $A = \sqrt {\frac{{{B^2}{{\left( {1 + {t^2}} \right)}^2}}}{{4{t^2} + {{\left( {{S_1}} \right)}^2}}}}$. An interesting fact is that Mathematica show that this minimizer can be achieve in the following cases:

**Cases 1:**
$t =  - 1 + \sqrt 2 $ this means that $\theta  = \frac{\pi }{4}$

**Cases 2:**
$0 < t <  - 1 + \sqrt 2 $ so $0 < \theta  < \frac{\pi }{4}$

**Cases 3:**
$ - 1 + \sqrt 2  < t < 1$ so $\frac{\pi }{4} < \theta  < \frac{\pi }{2}$

Among all of these cases, this equality happens $C = \sqrt {\frac{{1 + 2{t^2} + {t^4}}}{{{B^2}\left( {4{a^2}{t^2} + {S_2}^2} \right)}}} $. I guess that this is an important result to construct the proof.

How to proof that this result is correct since Mathematica hide all the reasoning step ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: If you want to "prove" the results, then that is a [`mathematics`](https://math.stackexchange.com/) issue not a Mathematica one. In Mathematica, user-defined symbols should not be or start with capital letters to avoid naming conflicts with built-in usage. For example, `C` and `D` have predefined meanings in Mathematica. In Mathematica, it is also generally better to avoid subscripts and/or superscripts except in output formatting (e.g., display an indexed variable as subscripts: `Format[s[n_]] = Subscript[s, n]`)

Comment: Your code produces a long and complicated result. Its `LeafCount` performs `5009`.